# Bypassing AWS KMS API decrypt call when / if no connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, sdk

In developing client side encryption with AWS KMS Encryption SDK there are extension possibilities with the CMM, but are there any standard ways of temporarily bypassing connectivity problems?

Answer (score 0):

The Encryption SDK uses a [wrapping key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/configure.html#config-keys) to encrypt/decrypt a data key, which is then used to encrypt/decrypt the stored message (and is stored with the message in encrypted form).

You can configure the library to use a locally-defined wrapping key, in which case you don't need connectivity. But if you use a KMS CMK as your wrapping key, then you do. One of the strengths of KMS is that the CMK key material never leaves AWS.

Comment: Much appreciated - so it's one or the other and not a fix to a temporary connectivity problem?

Comment: Correct. There's no way to decrypt a KMS-encrypted value without connecting to KMS.